# How to prevent ADO from altering my SQL command text?

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge, windows-xp, adodb, sqloledb

i am running a `MERGE` statement against an SQL Server 2008 R2 database (which is in 2008 compatibility mode).

The exact merge statement SQL is irrelevant, but here is an example of a MERGE statement:

```
MERGE Users
USING (VALUES 
('{77410DC5-7A3E-4F1A-82C6-8EFB3068DE66}')
) AS rows(UserGUID)
ON Users.UserName = rows.UserName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
DELETE; --always end MERGE with semi-colon
```

When executing this statement from SSMS, or from a client PC running Windows 7, it executes correctly.

But when my software is running on a client PC that is Windows XP or Windows Server 2003 R2, the sql `CommandText` is being altered before reaching the server. In the SQL Server Profiler, i can see the SQL being executed is:

```
exec MERGE Users
USING (VALUES 
('{77410DC5-7A3E-4F1A-82C6-8EFB3068DE66}')
) AS rows(UserGUID)
ON Users.UserName = rows.UserName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
DELETE; --always end MERGE with semi-colon
```

Which is not valid SQL, and SQL Server throws the error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'MERGE'
```

You can confirm that it is invalid SQL by trying to execute it against your SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

Peter Boulton reported the same issue on the Microsoft forums:

> [SQL MERGE syntax works with Win7 SP1 client but fails with earlier platforms](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/96550daa-94e4-437a-b09a-466686c35e73)
>
> I believe ADO parses the SQL before it sends it to the server.  The data access components were updated for Win7 SP1 and also WinServer 2008 R2.  However, I believe XP SP3's data access components predate SQL Server 2008.
>
> That's why the SQL works from Win7 SP1 but not from XP.
>
> My *'solution'* was to wrap the SQL in an `EXEC` so that ADO allows it through, as in:
>
> EXEC('MERGE....etc.')

His hack certainly works, change:

```
MERGE Users ...
```

into

```
EXEC('MERGE Users' ...)
```

but i'd like to come up with the real solution. I don't know who in the chain is responsible for altering my command text:

> ADO -> OLEDB -> SQLOLEDB -> SQL Server

but i want them to stop.

How do i, through ADO, specify my command text, and have SQLOLEDB not modify it?

Right now my code is<sup>1</sup>:

```
String sqlCommandText = "MERGE Users" //snip;
int recordsAffected;

connection.Execute(
    sqlCommandText, 
    out recordsAffected, 
    adCmdText | adExecuteNoRecords);
```

i do not see any [`ExecuteOptionEnum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676517%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or [`CommandTypeEnum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to tell ADO, and underlying providers, to treat the text as *raw*.

---

For now the fixup hack is:

```
sql = "MERGE Users" ...

ExecuteNoRecords(connection, sql);
```

with the modified helper:

```
int ExecuteNoRecords(Connection connection, String sql)
{
   //20130611: Fix bug in ADO that mangles/breaks SQL it doesn't understand (e.g. MERGE on Windows XP)
   String obfuscatedCommandText = 'EXEC(' + QuotedStr(sql)+ ')';

   int recordsAffected;

   connection.Execute(obfuscatedCommandText, out recordsAffected, adCmdText | adExecuteNoRecords);

   return recordsAffected;
}
```

## Update: A better workaround hack

Rather than wrapping the entire statement in `EXEC(...)`, i found a safer trick to defeating ADO is to precede the statement with a comment. Even an empty comment will do:

```
--
MERGE Users
USING (VALUES ...
```

In reality you will want to have some text explaining that the empty comment line is **critical** to making the query work:

```
--Leading comment to thwart ADO from mangling MERGE on Windows XP/2003R2
MERGE Users
USING (VALUES ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no solution, and ADO (while not *dead*) is done, the hack **is** the answer.

Never issue a `MERGE` statement without a leading comment line:

```
--Dummy leading comment line to thwart ADO from mangling MERGE on Windows XP/2003R2
MERGE Users
USING (VALUES ...
```

Comment: Also statements starting with "with" for CTE functions are also affected!

Comment: @BerndOtt That's a good note; and a horrifying reality. I now have to undergo another round of reviewing all code everywhere. :(